# Lighthouse command line app just waits for browser forever

Tags: performance

I am running the Node Lighthouse CLI on Mac M2 Pro with Node version v21.1.0 installed by NVM.

When I do `lighthouse anyurl` what I get is something that looks like this

```
  LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser. +0ms
  LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser... +1ms
  LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..... +503ms
  LH:ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....✓ +2ms
```

where the waiting for browser lasts forever and the only thing I see in the address field of Chrome is "about:blank"

The browser has been launched, the window sort of turns a bit white to indicated that ChromeLauncher is waiting I guess.

Any ideas why the browser is not getting controlled, why it is not going to a url.

As any example of urls not working
http://google.com https://gpogle.com https://kfumspejderne.dk/

Nothing, just waiting for browser.